# Active admin e Devise na aplicação

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Nessa app em que estou trabalhando utilizo o active admin e na aplicação utilizo o Devise. Ambos o utilizam para login.

Quando fiz logout do /admin sou redirecionado para tela principal do usuário final que se inicia com uma tela de login.

A questão é que ao tentar acessar o /admin novamente sou redirecionado para esta tela de login do usuário final e não me deixa acessar a tela /admin até eu logar como um usuário final. Quando logo como usuário posso acessar a tela de /admin e aí sim entro com login e senha de admin e consigo acesso.

No log do terminal ao acessar o /admin me retorna:

```
Started GET "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-15 03:05:07 -0300
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após alguns restarts na minha app magicamente voltou a funcionar. Ainda assim um bug estranho.

Procurei e encontrei essa issue que fala sobre isso, para caso ocorra com alguém algum dia algo do tipo:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1661

Comment: Se você trabalha sempre com servidor instânciado, não esqueca de encerra-lo e iniciar novamente, através do `rails server`.

Comment: O estranho foi por que esta configuração que é sugerida na issue fica em um initializer e no meu caso já estava tudo certo. Mas em um dos meus restarts foi como se não tivesse inicializado essa configuração especificamente.